# in Powerbi can you count the number of rows with the same ID , conditional on one of the rows having an indicator?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to count the number of times each ID is occurring in the table based on an indicator variable.

I am very new to PowerBI but have tried to show what I want to do below :

ID          INDICATOR

11233        0
43145        0
43145        0
11233        0
11233        1
44517        1

So I would like to see that for ID # 11233 there is a count of 3 IDs, for ID# 43145 there are 0, etc..

If I could get the following output it would also work :

ID          INDICATOR      INDICATOR2

11233       0               1
43145       0               0
43145       0               0
11233       0               1
11233       1               1
44517       1               1

and from this I know how to make a sum of the indicator2 .

If someone knows a solution to this it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: So are you trying to do a distinct count of IDs which have at least one row with `Indicator` value of 1 ?

Comment: I am trying to get the amount of times an ID occurs , given it has one row with indicator value of 1. I marked a solution already as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new **Column** or **Measure** using this below code. **Column** is preferred for further use.

```
indicator2_measure = 
CALCULATE(
    max('your_table_name'[INDICATOR]),
    ALLEXCEPT('your_table_name','your_table_name'[ID])
)
```

output-

[image]

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks a lot! This is such a simple yet effective solution. I managed to complete what I wanted to do easily after this.

Regards, Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new column in your table then use:

To show on each row how many time current ID occured (and at least one has INDICATOR ==1

```
HowMany = var currow = 'Table'[ID]
var ID_withIndicator = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[ID]),'Table'[INDICATOR] ==1)
return
CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'), filter(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[ID] = currow && 'Table'[ID] in ID_withIndicator))
```

OR

Set a 0/1 flag to each row

```
INDICATOR2 = var currow = 'Table'[ID]
var ID_withIndicator = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[ID]),'Table'[INDICATOR] ==1)
return
CALCULATE( COUNTX(ID_withIndicator, 1)) +0
```

[image]

OR use a measure to count:

```
Measure = var currow = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[ID])
var ID_withIndicator = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[ID]),'Table'[INDICATOR] ==1)
return
CALCULATE( countrows('Table'), FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[ID] in ID_withIndicator && 'Table'[ID] = currow )) + 0
```

[image]

Comment: Hi ,

Thanks for your extensive answer. I used the answer that I selected, but I am going to give this a shot as well during the week and will let you know if I manage to get it to work. I figure it will be a very good learning experience to try your method! 

Many thanks, Chris